# how to write the condition in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two text input fields like so:

```
<input type="text" id="test1".../>
<input type="text" id="test2".../>
```

Now I want the visitor to only be able to fill in only one of those text inputs. For example, if `#test1` has a value, when the visitor tries to enter a value into `#test2`, an alert a box should say "Fill in either test1 or test2 but not both".

Comment: Please do not use alert boxes for that but rather disable the other textbox. Alert boxes are usually very annoying...

Comment: thanks for your tips.,if don't use alert.how to disable the other textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple `text` s . USE CLASS. And also the below code will not disable, but does not let focus on it. If you want the disabled, then use the following code

```
$('.text').keyup(
    function (){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {                
            $('.text').not($(this)).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }        
        else{
            $('.text').not($(this)).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
)
```

Something like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/LaHtL/2/)**.

```
$('.text').focus(
    function (){
        if($('.text').not($(this)).val() != '')
        {
            alert("Please Enter only one value");
            $('.text').not($(this)).focus();
        }        
    }
)
```

And HTML

```
<input id="test1" type="text" class="text"/>
<input id="test2" type="text" class="text"/>
```

Comment: if don't use alert.how to disable the other textbox. thank you

Comment: i can't use  type="text" because there are 5 input box. how to alter your code. experimentX thank you

Comment: @enjoylive are you sure that you have only two textbox.

Comment: @enjoylife well, you can use class to the elements where you want to add that feature, also the code has been updated. http://jsfiddle.net/LaHtL/4/

Comment: what's this $('.text').not($(this)).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); line meaning? thank you. what's keyup and fouse differece?

Comment: @enjoylife the code you mentioned, adds attribute `disabled` to the `.text`. And since we might hit backspace and the value might be null, the other element has to be enabled back, so keyup is used.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, this is what you need.

```
$('#test1, #test2').keyup(function() {
    var $id = this.id;    
    if ($id == 'test1' && $('#test2').val().length) {
        alert('test2 already have a value');
        $('#test1').val('');
    } else if ($id == 'test2' && $('#test1').val().length) {
        alert('test1 already have a value');
        $('#test2').val('');
    }
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/4dqUx/3/

Comment: $('#test1').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#test2').val().length) {
        alert('test2 already have a value');
        $(this).val('');
    }
})
$('#test2').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#test1').val().length) {
        alert('test1 already have a value');
        $(this).val('');
    }
})

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
Test1<input id="test1" type="text"/><br/><br/>
Test2<input id="test2" type="text"/>
```

CSS

```
input{
border:1px solid black;
margin-left:20px;
}
```

jquery

```
$('#test1').keyup(function() {
if ($('#test2').val().length > 0) {
    alert('test2 already has a value');
    $(this).val('');
    $("#test1").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
}
})
$('#test2').keyup(function(){
if ($('#test1').val().length > 0) {
    alert('test1 already has a value');
    $(this).val('');
    $("#test2").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
}
});
```

You can also see it on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/gpmattoo/jPBsk/) It provides the alert as well as disables the check box.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id=test1" class="test" type="text"...../>
<input id="test2" class="test" type="text"...>



$(".test").focus(function() {
 var isTextEntered=false;
 var current = $(this);
 $(".test").each( function() {

     if ($(this).attr("id") !=current.attr("id") &&  $(this).val() != "")
             isTextEntered= true;

  });

 if (isTextEntered)
    alert("text already entered in other item")

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use such solution:

1) add `data-group` and `data-msg` attribute to your inputs, like:

```
<input type='text' data-group='group1' data-msg='Only field1'>
<input type='text' data-group='group1' data-msg='Only field2'>
<input type='text' data-group='group1' data-msg='Only field3'>
<input type='text' data-group='group1' data-msg='Only field4'>
```

This attributes would be used to detect unique field group and to display associated message in some info `div`:

```
<div id='message' data-defmsg='Fill one of this fields'></div>
```

2) Use some JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    // Let's find message DIV and...
    var $message = $('#message');
    // set default message
    $message.html($message.data('defmsg'));

    // Now lets find all text inputs in group1
    var unique_fields_in_group1 = $("input[type=text][data-group=group1]");


    // Let's attach on change event 
    unique_fields_in_group1.keyup(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        // Now we detect what to do next:
        // If user fiiled text box up...
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            // ... we disable others
            unique_fields_in_group1.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $this.removeAttr('disabled');
            // .. and show help message from filled input
            $message.html($this.data('msg'));
        } else {
            // When user cleared text box
            // we'd unlock all inputs
            unique_fields_in_group1.removeAttr('disabled');
            // and restore default help message
            $message.html($message.data('defmsg'));
        }
    });
    unique_fields_in_group1.change(function() {
        $(this).keyup();
    });
});
```

[Full example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7eCX/5/)

**UPD: Some explanations**

- `$message` - variable to store reference to `div` with `id='message'`;
- `$message.html('MSG')` -- sets HTML value into associated `div`; result of this call is `<div>MSG</div>` ([JQuery.html API](http://api.jquery.com/html/))
- `$message.data('def-msg')` -- retrieves value from div's attribute `data-defmsg` ([jQuery.data API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/))
- `unique_fields_in_group1.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` -- just adds `disabled` attribute to all fields in array, so browser will disable these input fields ([How to disable/enable an element with jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-disableenable-element-with.html))
- `input[type=text][data-group=group1]` - is CSS selector to get all inputs with have `type` = `text` and attribute `data-group` = `group1`

**UPD2**

Added handler for CHANGE event, to correctly handle mouse copy/paste events.

[Old example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7eCX/4/)

Comment: your code is too hard for me. i am sorry i am a niwbie of programming.what's  $message.html and $message.data('defmsg'),unique_fields_in_group1.attr('disabled', 'disabled');meaning.;why used this input[type=text][data-group=group1]

Comment: @enjoylife - I'd update my answer with answers for your questions.

Answer (score 1):

2 event binds that make switching between form fields very easy, [find demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/atEV8/1/):

```
$('input[type="text"]').live('focus', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() !== '' && id !== this.id) {
            $('input[type="text"]').not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            alert('Fill in either test1 or test2 but not both!');
            return false;
        };
    });
});

$('input[type="text"]').live('click', function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```